# output excel file using write.xlsx in R is not writing the column having no name

Tags: r, export-to-excel

The dataset in R workspace looks like:

```
       row.names             qs
1   2015-04-01 09:30:00 0.205305233
2   2015-04-01 09:30:00 0.205305233
3   2015-04-01 10:00:00 0.135785061
4   2015-04-01 10:00:00 0.135785061
5   2015-04-01 10:30:00 0.160509554
6   2015-04-01 10:30:00 0.160509554
```

this data goes up to 2000 points
When the dataset file is written using the code:

```
require(xlsx)#loading excel write package
write.xlsx(dataset, file = file.path("F:\\sample_output", paste0("CAN_all_temp",".xlsx")),sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

The output is like:
    qs
1   0.205305233
2   0.205305233
3   0.135785061
4   0.135785061
5   0.160509554
6   0.160509554
In this output column 1 with timestamps goes missing. Kindly help in writing this missing column in excel.

Answer (score 0):

is row.names class type is Date? change class of your row.names column to character using

```
data$row.names<-as.character(data$row.names)
```

export to excel

```
write.xlsx(data,file="output.xlsx")
```

Write.xlsx has trouble writing date class type to excel and you will have to set a custom format of date prior to xlsx command if you really want to do so.

Comment: ....Many thanks for the answer but still it is not working ...the error is ..Error in error(x, ...) : 
  improper length of one or more arguments to merge.xts...I also tried ..datasetr$row.names<-as.POSIXct(datasetr$row.names, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Error in as.POSIXct.default(datasetr$row.names, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") : ..bit it shows the error as...
  do not know how to convert 'datasetr$row.names' to class “POSIXct”

Comment: are you saying that you converted your row.names to character vector and still its giving error in writing it to xlsx? why are you trying to convert to as.POSIXct?